# Protocol exception error

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, ssis, basichttpbinding

I'm trying to call soap service in script task but getting this following error. I've added a serviceReference through wsdl url. I don't have idea about what this error is referring to. However i'm able to get the data in SOAPUI
"The header 'ReliableMessaging' from the namespace 'http://sap.com/xi/XI/Message/30' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding."

below is the code i'm using

```
EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://sapnxcci.intel.com:8220/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&senderService=MC4510&receiverParty=&receiverService=&interface=Segments&interfaceNamespace=http://intel.com/xi/Intel-MDM/Project/Segment");

        SegmentsClient client = new SegmentsClient(BindingUtility.GetInitiativesBinding(), endPointAddress);
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "sys_idwcons";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "abdc";

        SegmentResponse results = client.ListSegments(new SegmentRequest() { SegmentName = "" });
```

In GetInitiativesBinding contains the following.

```
 public static BasicHttpBinding GetInitiativesBinding()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        return binding;
    }
```

and my App.Config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SegmentsBinding" />
            <binding name="SegmentsBinding1">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://sapnxcci.intel.com:8420/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;senderService=MC4510&amp;receiverParty=&amp;receiverService=&amp;interface=Segments&amp;interfaceNamespace=http%3A%2F%2Fintel.com%2Fxi%2FIntel-MDM%2FProject%2FSegment"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SegmentsBinding"
          contract="ServiceReference1.Segments" name="HTTP_Port" />
      <endpoint address="https://sapnxcci.intel.com:8220/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;senderService=MC4510&amp;receiverParty=&amp;receiverService=&amp;interface=Segments&amp;interfaceNamespace=http%3A%2F%2Fintel.com%2Fxi%2FIntel-MDM%2FProject%2FSegment"
           binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SegmentsBinding1"
           contract="ServiceReference1.Segments" name="HTTPS_Port" />
     </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the return message from PI contains the  tags.
 tags are only useful when you have a PI - PI connection.

Reference: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1839924